# Python subprocess aws copy - maximize network bandwidth

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, subprocess, throughput

Running python 3.4.2 on a box that supposedly offers >1Gbps throughput, I have the following code in a loop of contents that basically downloads from s3 into stdin and pipes to another s3 bucket via stdout:

```
from_command = "aws --endpoint-url {0}  s3 cp {1} - --profile={2}".format(endpoint_url, cleversafe_url.replace("cleversafe","s3"), from_profile)
to_command = "aws s3 cp - {0}/{1} --expected-size={2} --profile={3}".format(s3_bucket, filename, content_size, to_profile)
#args are just breaking up to_command:                                
args = ['aws', 's3', 'cp', '-', '{0}/{1}'.format(s3_bucket, filename), '--expected-size={0}'.format(content_size), '--profile={0}'.format(to_profile)]
p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, bufsize=-1)
output = p.communicate(from_command.encode("ascii"))
```

Monitoring via nload, the highest output rate I've seen is around 180Mbps. Is there anything code-wise I can do to increase this throughput? (Box is Debian 8.11.)

Comment: Why not use boto3 to interact with s3 through python?

Comment: It's not clear from your question whether your Debian box is an EC2 instance or not. If it's outside the AWS ecosystem, it's likely S3 isn't going to provide the upload bandwidth to take full advantage of that gigabit throughput (assuming by 'throughput' you do mean specifically just upload throughput and not download or total).

Comment: @kungphu The box is indeed an EC2 instance.

Comment: Are they in the same region/AZ? Is the instance type rated for _at least_ 1Gbps, _up to_ 1Gbps, or something else? Have you tried just downloading to disk then uploading from disk to S3 to see if piping like this might be slowing your transfer down? Are you aware you can `aws s3 cp` a file from one bucket directly to another?

Comment: @kungphu The from and to s3 urls are for completely different accounts with completely different credentials; the source uses an endpont-url argument and the target does not. Downloading to a temp file then reuploading is not feasible due to the file sizes (tens of GB). After much research I realize that p.communicate probably won't work for me because it buffers the entire file before writing the output stream.

Comment: @kpdude I was suggesting the temp file download/upload as a speed test, not a solution, to see if it's your pipe approach was causing the bottleneck. I have no way of knowing what your access is, but I'm currently using the direct s3 cp approach between buckets in different accounts by setting up a single role with the appropriate permissions on each bucket. So it can be done, but how feasible it is likely depends on the IT/ops bureaucracy you have to deal with.